# expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'if'

Tags: c, linux-kernel, battery

i am getting an error while compiling linux kernel for android...

I modded a battery driver:

here there is the commit on github and all the file: https://github.com/Lopicl/android_samsung_thunderkernel_cooperve/commit/6385d6206119a3f8551e17bbeae130d3230965bf

When compiling i am getting an error:

```
drivers/power/max8986-power.c:188: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'if'
```

Can u please help me? :)

Thanks in advance,
Matteo

Comment: The code that your link is pointing look quite unusual :) Putting `if/else` constructs around `#define` makes no sense at all. Please try to learn the basics of C, first.

Comment: okay, fine, but what could I do instead? :)

Comment: note the difference between `#if` and `if` these are completely different concepts in C. Get yourself a good book or begginers site and read.

Comment: for the off topic holders: i have put the valid code, just linked it because the question has been very long. and i solved the problem, i wrote how in a comment of the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things with a # before them are processed only once, when your code is compiled; they are *not* processed at run time. This makes, for example, the following code bad:

```
if (max8986_power->isFullcharged == TRUE)
{
    #define FULLY_CHARGED 1
}
else
{
    #define FULLY_CHARGED 0
}
```

because you will in effect `#define FULLY_CHARGED x` twice (the pre-processor ignores the actual C code; the `if` checks are not used).

Later when you `if (FULLY_CHARGED = 0)` you are not only attempting to examine an invalidly defined macro, but your code is attempting to *assign* the value rather than just examine it! *IF* `FULLY_CHARGED` was a variable, you would mean your code to be `if (FULLY_CHARGED == 0)` (note the double equal signs, for equality checking).

Perhaps you want to change the definition of your macro to:

```
#if defined CONFIG_BLX
    #define FULLY_CHARGED (max8986_power->batt_percentage == MAX_CHARGINGLIMIT) && (max8986_power->charging_status == POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_CHARGING)
#else
    #define FULLY_CHARGED  (max8986_power->isFullcharged == TRUE)
#endif
```

and fix all your IF statements to check for equality rather than assignment.

Comment: Ok thanks, now i fixed using a new method ;) https://github.com/Lopicl/android_samsung_thunderkernel_cooperve/commit/08ccbbc52801b06542a8fea59893aaae6c2537ca

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using C-preprocessor `#if`'s and `#else`'s not C-language `if`'s and `else`'s.

Comment: FULLY_CHARGED is defined in `if` blocks due to the dynamic nature of things, not a static definition... this makes preprocessor-based assignment in what otherwise looks like his code invalid. I.e., `#if (max8986_power->batt_percentage = MAX_CHARGINGLIMIT) && (max8986_power->charging_status = POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_CHARGING)` is not going to work.